# C++ vector of pairs initialization

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have

```
vector< pair<int, int>> myVec (N);
```

I want to have all pairs initialized to -1,-1.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include <utility>

vector<pair<int, int>> myVec (N, std::make_pair(-1, -1));
```

The second argument to that constructor is the initial value that the N pairs will take.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks! I have to wait 12 minutes to accept answer though.

Comment: is it possible to initialize vector to different values, i.e. provide pair for each vector element?

Comment: Yes, using initializer lists: `vector<pair<int, int>> myVec = { {-1, -1}, {2, 5}, {3, 10} };`

Comment: initializer lists requires c++0x standard.

Answer (score 31):

Just to add some additional info (not quite what the Asker wanted, but asked for in the comments of the accepted answer):

Individual initialization can be done with (C++11):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec1 = { {1, 0}, {2,0}, {3,1} };

std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec2 = {std::make_pair(1, 0),
                                           std::make_pair(2, 0),
                                           std::make_pair(3, 0)};
```

In old C++ standards, something like this would work:

```
const std::pair<int,int> vals[3] = {std::make_pair(1, 0),
                                    std::make_pair(2, 0),
                                    std::make_pair(3, 0)};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec2 (&vals[0], &vals[0] + 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **initialize all pairs**, maybe you can do something like this:

```cpp
vector<pair<int, int>> directions {
    {1, 0},
    {-1, 0},
    {0, 1},
    {0, -1},    
};
```

Here, 4 pairs have been initialized as such.